# Get Website Id on multi website on Cart Page

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, products, websites

I am trying to get the websites ids against each product on cart page like this but didn't work.

```
 <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item):
              echo "<pre/>";
              $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId());
               print_r($product->getWebsiteIds());
             echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
            <?php endforeach ?>
```

It showing output with `1` result.Some product belongs to website 2

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
)
```

Comment: What is the file you are working on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code as below.

```
<?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item):
              echo "<pre/>";
              $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());
               print_r($product->getWebsiteIds() );
             echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
            <?php endforeach ?>
```